# cleveref: changing conjunction for pair

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I want to change the conjunction used for a pair of equations. It keeps printing "and", I've tried a few different with \crefpairconjunction but I just can't get it to work. I didn't find anything which helps when googling around. Below is a minimal working example, the stuff in the preamble is what's currently in my report, is this affecting it?

Many thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress, % on multiple refs sort them and write as range
        capitalise, % Use Section not section etc.
        noabbrev, % Use Table not Tab. etc.
        nameinlink % Make the name (eg Section) part of the hyperlink
        ]{cleveref}
% just use (...) for equations
\crefformat{equation}{#2(#1)#3}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}{ and~(#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and~(#2#1#3)}

% Except for start of sentences where we need to say "Equations"
\Crefformat{equation}{Equation~#2(#1)#3}
\Crefrangeformat{equation}{Equations~#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}
\Crefmultiformat{equation}{Equations~(#2#1#3)}{ and~(#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and~(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
e_1
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_2
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

This has an `and' \cref{eq1,eq2}

But I want this: \cref{eq1}--\cref{eq2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but still of relevance: Since you've set the option `nameinlink`, you should probably change `\Crefrangeformat{equation}{Equations~#3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}` to `\Crefrangeformat{equation}{#3Equations~(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}`, i.e., include "Equations~" inside the scope of the hypertarget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the instruction

```
\newcommand\crefpairconjunction{--}
```

in the preamble.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}% just for this example
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newcommand\crefpairconjunction{--}
\crefname{equation}{}{} % no "equation[s]" label mid-sentence
\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} e_1 \label{eq1} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} e_2 \label{eq2} \end{equation}

This expression no longer has an `and': \cref{eq1,eq2}.

And this one doesn't either: \Cref{eq1,eq2} \dots
\end{document}
```

For more information on the `\crefpairconjunction` macro, I recommend p. 13 of the user guide of the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/) package.

Comment: Strangely enough, taking out the the line "\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}" puts the "and"s back in. I haven't read through page 13 yet, doing that now. Many thanks.

Comment: Works fine without the "\Crefname{equation}" line for me, at least with the latest pre-release available from my web site: http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.html  Perhaps an update fixed whatever bug was causing that.