# Why doesn't cleveref work in Portuguese?

Tags: babel, cleveref

I'm using `cleveref` in a document in Portuguese, but the reference of the chapter is in English? How I can fix this? Here it is a sample of my code:

```
\documentclass[portuges]{report}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}\label{intro}

Este é o meu \Cref{intro}...

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!  If you use pdfLaTeX than remove option `dvips,`. Also it is sufficient to set `prtugese` once, for example only as option of document class. Considering this, your document example works fine, as is expected.

Comment: And if I'm compiling the file as dvi->ps->pdf? Indeed, that's the case because I've also some pictures in PSTricks.

Comment: @JoséSantos `hyperref` knows what engine is being used. The `dvips` option should not be used.

Answer (score 3):

There is no support in `cleveref` for Portugal Portuguese, only for Brazilian.

Look in `cleveref.sty` from line 7397 to 7619 to see whether there is something to change to adapt the Brazilian locale to Portugal Portuguese. You need

```
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink,brazilian]{cleveref}
```

and to do the necessary changes (if any). Then ask the maintainer to add support for the language.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to redefine the `cleveref` expressions for Portuguese:

```
% "cleveref" Portuguese names.
\crefname{equation}{equação}{equações}
\Crefname{equation}{Equação}{Equações}
\crefname{table}{tabela}{tabelas}
\Crefname{table}{Tabela}{Tabelas}
\crefname{figure}{figura}{figuras}
\Crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}
\crefname{chapter}{capítulo}{capítulos}
\Crefname{chapter}{Capítulo}{Capítulos}
\crefname{section}{secção}{secções}
\Crefname{section}{Secção}{Secções}

% Changing conjunctions. See "cleveref" documentation.
% https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275828/cleveref-changing-conjunction-for-pair
\renewcommand*{\crefpairconjunction}{\ e\ }
\renewcommand*{\crefmiddleconjunction}{,\ }
\renewcommand*{\creflastconjunction}{, e\ }
\renewcommand*{\crefrangeconjunction}{\ a\ }

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apêndice}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apêndices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apêndices}

\crefname{appendix}{apêndice}{apêndices}
\Crefname{appendix}{Apêndice}{Apêndices}
```

I've been using this code for my [University of Aveiro thesis template](https://github.com/ruiantunes/ua-thesis-template/blob/main/tex/config/language/expressions/portuguese.tex) without problems.

Comment: This should work if the document is only in Portuguese, but you may be tripped if `babel` is at play and `\selectlanguage` is used somewhere in the document.

Comment: Off-topic: I've noticed you just use `\sloppy` for the whole document "To make text never go over the right margin." I would suggest you consider using `microtype` *instead* of this, for much better results.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks @gusbrs! I'll look into it =]